# sed command to replace code in file and save

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have an HTML file with some content that I would like to remove when I compile my application.

The content that needs to be removed is prefixed with `"<!-- BEGIN -->"` and postfixed with `"<!-- END -->"`. So everything between these 2 tags (and including the tags) needs to go.

```
<!-- BEGIN -->
Remove me
<!-- END -->
```

I believe the following command will simply comment-out all the code:

```
# remove content between comments
cat src/html/project.html                                       \
| sed -e 's/<!-- BEGIN -->/<!-- BEGIN /' \
| sed -e 's/<!-- END -->/     END -->/' \
> dist/html/project.html
```

Resulting in this:

```
 <!-- BEGIN 
    Remove me
    END -->
```

Commenting out the code is not exactly what I want, but I guess it will do. However, even in this case it is generating a syntax error:

```
./shell: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Even better, if anyone can suggest how to remove the code (including the tags), that would be ideal.

Sorry if the problem is obvious, I'm a complete novice with this stuff.

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`? `perl`, `python` or even just `awk` would work better for something like this.

Comment: you said you don't want to comment out those lines, you want to remove them from the file? say, `<!-- BEGIN....whatever in between till END -->` ?

Comment: @miorel - awk would be fine too... or any other command for that matter. I just don't know how the syntax. So if you have any suggestions, that would be great. @ Kent - Yes, exactly.

Comment: The syntax errors are because your pipe symbols should be at the end of each line, not at the start of the next line. You also don't need to escape the newlines once it's written correctly. Finally, sed you do not need cat and a pipe as sed can open files just as easily as cat can. That's known as UUOC (google it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that:

- the `BEGIN` and `END` comments are always paired
- you are sure that the format is fixed: `<!-- (onespace) BEGIN/END (onespace) -->`
- and the `BEGIN, END` comment sits in its own line:

this will do the work:

```
 sed '/<!-- BEGIN -->/,/<!-- END -->/d' file
```

if we make an example:

```
kent$  cat file
<!-- BEGIN -->
Remove me

<!-- END -->
we
<!-- BEGIN -->
22Remove me
<!-- END -->
need
<!-- BEGIN -->
33Remove me
33Remove me
<!-- END -->
this
<!-- BEGIN -->
44Remove me
<!-- END -->

kent$  sed '/<!-- BEGIN -->/,/<!-- END -->/d' file
we
need
this
```

if you want to save back to your file, you could use `-i` option of sed.
also  you don't need the `cat` to pass file content to `sed`

Comment: Thanks @Kent, I'm going to give this a shot

Comment: In the end, this was my solution. Thanks Kent :) And thanks everyone else for your answers!

Comment: Allowing a little more flexibility in Kent's second assumption, you could use the slightly more complicated RE `sed -E '/<!--[[:blank:]]+BEGIN[[:blank:]]+-->/,/<!--[[:blank:]]+END[[:blank:]]+-->/d' file` or replace the `+` with `*` for the whitespace to be optional.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all unnecessary piped commands:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/\(<!-- BEGIN \)-->/\1/' -e 's/<!--\( END -->\)/    \1/' src/html/project.html
```

As your question says you probably want to remove content between 2 tags then use:

```
sed -i.bak '/<!-- BEGIN -->/,/<!-- END -->/d' src/html/project.html
```

`-i.bak` will make inline change into the given file and save a copy of original with `.bak` file extension.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just tried this and am getting a syntax error. Could you tell me what's wrong with this: cat app/index.php 
| sed -e 's/\(<!-- BEGIN \)-->/\1/' -e 's/<!--\( END -->\)/    \1/' 
> build/app/index.php

Comment: Pls don't use cat and pipe. As I suggested above you can directly call sed on a file. Also pls make sure to put a backslash before ( and ) as shown above.

Comment: But what if I want to put this into a shell script and run as part of a job?

Comment: ...also I should have noted that I don't want to replace the file but create a copy. The -i.bak option will create a backup but I would rather create an entirely new file and leave the source alone.

Comment: ALright in that case don't use `-i.bak` option and redirect sed's output to any other file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to remove a block of lines, including the start and end markers is:

```
sed -e '/<!-- BEGIN -->/,/<!-- END -->/d' src/html/project.html
```

But if both markers could be on the same line, then you need to add a bit more to it:

```
sed -e '/<!-- BEGIN -->.*<!-- END -->/{d;b;};/<!-- BEGIN -->/,/<!-- END -->/d' src/html/project.html
```